# Using getDeclaredMethod to get a private method of any super (parent) class

Tags: java, reflection

I need to call a private method via reflection. In advance I don't kow if that private method is part of the specified class or a super class. I have the name of the private method, their parameters and their parameter types.
My first approach was the following:

```
Object classToTest = ....;
ArrayList<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>();
Class<?> classIndex = classToTest.getClass();

//iterate over (super) classes to collect all methods
do{
    methods.addAll(Arrays.asList(classIndex.getDeclaredMethods()));
    classIndex = classIndex.getSuperclass();
}
while(classIndex.getClass()!=null);

for(Method method : methods){
 //match the right method
}
//call it
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(classToTest,parameterValues);
```

**Problem with that approach:** Getting the right method out of the list is not trivial as the sourcecode for .getDeclaredMethod(...) shows. Unfortunatly many private internal methods are used which thus cant't be reused...

The 2nd approach was to use the getDeclaredMethod() which does the matching for me:

```
Method method=null;
Class<?> classIndex = classToTest.getClass();

//iterate over (super) classes since private method may be inherited
do{
    //exception catching as part of the normal code is ugly 
    try{
        method = classIndex.getDeclaredMethod(nameOfMethod, parameterTypes);
        //method found thus exit
        break;
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme){
        //method not found thus check super class
        classIndex = classIndex.getSuperclass();
    }
}
while(classIndex!=null);

if(method==null) throw new NoSuchMethodException( classToTest.getClass().getName() + "." + nameOfMethod + Arrays.toString(parameterValues));

//no method matching necessary
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(classToTest,parameterValues);
```

**Disadvantage of that approach:** the exception catching as part of the code flow is ugly - however I currently don't see an alternative without reimplementing the matching code of Class.java.

**So does anyone see an alternative approach to get the right private method?**

Comment: How do you identify the method you are looking for? Which information on the method's signature do you have? Maybe you could wrap your examples in a `lookupMethod()` function to display your search parameters.

Comment: I have the name of the method and the parameters + their types

Comment: I would say that the second approach is the right one, let standard library do the matching. It's unfortunate that Java insists on throwing exceptions whenever someone sneezes, rather than returning null, which would be perfect in this case. But that's how it is.

Comment: IMO you can cache the method with its class which provides good performance....which is bad while  frequent  **getDeclaredMethod** call

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recursive extension method in Kotlin:

```
/** Recursively find a declared method in current and all super classes. */
private fun Class<*>.findMethod(methodName: String, vararg paramTypes: Class<*>): Method? =
    try {
        getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *paramTypes)
    } catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
        superclass?.findMethod(methodName, *paramTypes) ?: throw e
    }
```

Example Usage:

```
obj.javaClass.findMethod(methodName, *paramTypes)?.run {
    isAccessible = true
    invoke(obj, *params)
}
```